# Which sects of Hinduism do not agree with the concept of saguna brahman?

Tags: brahman, sects

Among all the sects of Sanathan Dharma, is there any sect that agrees with nirguna brahman, but does not agree with the idea of Saguna brahman?

If yes, what is the name(s) of the sect?

Comment: I think Lingayats (only theoretically).I have seen many of them worshiping  other gods like Ganesha ,devi etc.

Comment: First dvaita doesn't agree with 2 brahmans only one brahman existed he is having all auspicious qualities  advaita here too contradicts itself by having 2 brahmans